# OpenGL ES 2.0 Vertex skinning maximum number of bones?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, skinning, vertex

When drawing a vertex skinned model, what is the maximum number of bones per draw-call/batch for different iOS devices?

On OpenGL ES 1.1 the limit is set by the number of palette matrices, but how about OpenGL ES 2.0, what sets the limit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2.0 uses shaders for all of its vertex processing. So it depends on how many uniform matrices you can create. This is an implementation-defined limit, so it varies from hardware to hardware.

You can also use quaternions+position for bones instead of full matrices to save space.

Comment: If ES 2.0 supports vertex texturing you could also use textures for the transformation data, which probably offer much more memory. But I guess performance wouldn't be that great.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As specified by apple [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html) OpenGL ES 2.0 on the PowerVR SGX supports "up to 128 uniform vectors in a vertex shader". How does this translate to maximum number of uniform matrices?

Comment: @JonasBromö: It depends. If you use `mat4`s, then you divide the number by 4, so 32. If you use `mat3x4`s and do some transposition work, then you divide the number by 3, so 42. If you use quaternion+position as I suggested, that only takes 2 vectors, so you can have 64 of them. Minus of course any other uniforms you might need, like projection matrices or whatever.

Comment: Hi I dont believe this is the correct method. The vertex supports input of a float matrix array, which is similar to texture. This should support many matricies probably up to max size of a texture so were talking thousands of 3x3 matricies am I right?

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 7 you can access the texture units from the vertex shader, so you can make a texture, fill it with your matrices and access the matrices from your vertex shader. This will allow many more matrices to be accessed, at the expense of a more complex implementation.